# Convert BMP to PNG on right-click in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, png, file-conversion, bmp, image-formats

I want to select 1 or more BMP files in Windows 7 file explorer, right-click them, click "convert to PNG", and have them all replaced by PNGs with identical information.  What are some possible solutions to do this?

Currently I'm opening them in the GIMP and saving them as PNG and then deleting the BMP, but this requires a lot of effort.

Comment: I would go with a Python script for the image conversion.  Then add a context menu item that calls the script (search for "context verb" to find guides).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting something with one click is always tough, but this might be what you're looking for.

[XNView](https://www.xnview.com/)

Use it in conjunction with the shell extension, which offers a host of image manipulation options on right click.

[Addictive Tips: XNView shell extension](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/xnview-shell-extension-adds-image-converter-and-editor-in-right-click-context-menu/)

Comment: this works pretty well.  you select the images, right-click → XnShell → convert into → PNG, then press Delete to get rid of the old images.  and I've ended up using XnView as my main viewer, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Previously called "Right Click Image Converter", [ImageBadger](http://www.imagebadger.com/) is an image converter which has the capability to convert multiple images with right-click.

The program is a *shareware*. There's a try & buy version on the official site.

[image]

Comment: Does it delete the original files afterwards?

Comment: I did not try it but I don't think so; but since the files to be converted are selected, `Del+Enter` should be enough.

Comment: That looks like 2 or 3 clicks, plus the manual deletion, and I'd prefer free or DIY

Comment: @endolith: Good luck then.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP has a batch mode: see http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/
if GIMP is too heavy-weight for this application, there are probably other smaller packages that will do this which you can substitute.

You can create your own context item using "send to" and a batch file.

see: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/

command line parameters are %0-%9 (0 is the program, 1-9 are the parameters)

With some experimentation, you can probably roll your own. I have never attempted to send a list of files with this method.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/01/windows/image-photo/photo-magician-free-image-converter-and-image-resizer.html) is the tool you want but it is not free you have to buy it but it complete the requirement of yours to delete original files.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know how to that think, but did you consider some program with image batch processing?  You select all the files needed and have them converted to anything.

My choice is IrfanView because it is simple an lightweight and I did not feel the need to search for a better one. Corel PhotoPaint could also do that but that is a bit overkill.